# Shared/Final Layout switch/toggle button not available or visible

Tags: presentation, experience-editor

I'm using Sitecore 9.2. We have an issue where the shared/final layout button is available for some roles and not others in Experience Editor's Presentation Ribbon.

When I access a page with my admin account; the shared/final layout toggle button is available in the Experience Editor for a given page. However, when I access that same page from an author role; I can modify the page and edit the Presentation Details; but I can't toggle between shared and final layout as the button is not available on the EE ribbon.

I'm pretty sure this is an issue with permissions, but I can't find which role or permission I would need to assign to make this button visible for our author role. Googling has only led me to how to fix in Sitecore 8.1; but that's for the case that it doesn't show up at all for anyone; not just specific roles.

Roles assigned to this author role:

```
sitecore\Sitecore Client Advanced Publishing
sitecore\Designer
sitecore\Sitecore Client Users
sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring
```

Any ideas?

Comment: IIRC you need the `Designer` role

Comment: @MarkCassidy see my update for roles that were assigned to this author role.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. I needed to assign the Sitecore Author role to our custom role before the toggle would be available.